# Error with duplicated FileProvider in manifest.xml with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

How is it possible to have multiple provider of the same type in the manifest? Since the cordova camera plugins brings a file provider, our app can't be build anymore. In the manifest we have the following:

```
<provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>

<provider android:authorities="com.our.app.dev.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

The first entry comes from the camera plugin, the second from one of our plugins.

During build, the following error occurres:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:44:5-46:16 Error:
Element provider#android.support.v4.content.FileProvider at AndroidManifest.xml:44:5-46:16 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:41:5-43:16
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please remove and add again android platform .

Comment: Run: cordova clean android

Comment: @Eric: Tried 'cordova clean android'. Unfortunately, didn't help.

Comment: @Hassan: Complete reinstall of android platform didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Had you removed platform before reinstalling it  ? or Just reinstalled it again ?

Comment: @Hassan: 

Maybe i misunderstand you: Please specify 'removed'. I did: 1.) Deinstalled android (osx/ homebrew); 2.) Reinstalled it (osx/ homebrew); 3.) Downloaded necessary packages via "android" again 4.) Run cordova again. 

Question: Can you tell me, if this would be supposed to work? Can two provider of the same type (android.support.v4.content.FileProvider) exists in the manifest.xml. I don't understand yet, if it is our problem (wrong plugin.xml), a Cordova problem (wrong merging of plugin.xmls) or a Android problem (falsely unable to accept the two FileProvider). 

Thanks!

Comment: @Hassan: I also cleaned and rebuilded the complete cordova project. So, if you mean the cordova-android-platform (what i assume, now), then yes, it has been removed.

Comment: Now please upload your code on github i will make it correct for you don't worry.Thanks

Comment: Well thanks for the offer, but i rather would like to have an answer to my question from above: "Can two provider of the same type (android.support.v4.content.FileProvider) exists in the manifest.xml". Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is not a cordova problem but inside the android build process. At least i could reproduce it within a plain Android Studio and Gradle setup:

It seems that android is not OK with having two  tags with the same name attribute. I don't see why this is a problem as long as you have different authorities it should work fine. But this also leads to a solution:

within YOUR plugin (or your own fork of the plugin you want to use). You create your own FileProvider.java which just extends the original android.support.v4.content.FileProvider

```
package com.our.app.dev;

public class FileProvider extends android.support.v4.content.FileProvider {
}
```

within your plugin configuration you link to **this** FileProvider, which now has a different package name, thus avoiding this problem. Hope this works, for me it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Update: I filed a bug report on this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231824&thanks=231824&ts=1483974507

Comment: Update: I created a PR to solve this problem within the SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin which can be used as a reference workaround: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/pull/748

Answer (score 2):

**Just run this Command in your code editor, the jetifier will solve the problem**

```
    npm install jetifier
    npx jetify
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For reference: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#error-package-androidsupport-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

```
npx jetify
```

worked for our project. This modified the contents of the androidManifest file to point to the correct class